# Large integer multiplication isn't correct

Tags: c++

This I s what I got so far. Overall, I just need the multiplication fix small number are good when outputting. Large numbers are displaying the wrong output.

```
cout << "Enter an integer";
int finteger; cin >> finteger;
cout << "Enter another integer";
 int sinteger; cin >> sinteger;
int addition = finteger + sinteger;
int subtraction = finteger - sinteger;
int multiplication = finteger * sinteger;
//Outputting the answers along with the equations
cout << finteger << " + " << sinteger << " = " << addition << endl;
cout << finteger << " - " << sinteger << " = " << subtraction << endl;
cout << finteger << " * " << sinteger << " = " << multiplication << endl;
```

Comment: Which number do you call large? Did you consider that int is probably 32-bit on your system?

Comment: Most likely you're dealing with integer overflow. For signed integers the behavior of the whole program that triggers such overflow is undefined.

Comment: You may try to use `long long`.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the multiplied result is outside the range of an `int` on your platform. That's undefined behaviour. On some platforms the range can be as small as -32767 to +32767.

Despite all the advances over the years C++ still remains a ridiculously difficult language in which to perform even the simplest mathematical calculations without undefined behaviour creeping in somewhere.

The fact is that *all* your expressions are vulnerable to overflow!

If you're building a calculator from standard input then probably the simplest thing to do is to use a multi precision library such as the one that's part of the Boost distribution. [www.boost.org](http://www.boost.org).

Comment: I mean, the same effective issue exists in several other modern programming languages, it isn’t specific to C++. In particular, while integer overflow in e.g. Java and C# is well-defined, the end result in this case would be the same.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Although I have worked on a system that clamped an overflowed `int`. I don't think C# is allowed to do that. Java isn't for sure.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: And I don't think C# and Java ever make the assumption that a + c < b + c means that a < b for any constant c.

Comment: I didn’t mention clamping. Both C# and Java handle integer overflow by rolling over via modular arithmetic. Implementations aren’t only allowed to do this, they are *required* to do this, because it’s specified (in the case of C# only unless `checked` is used). And of course as a consequence they don’t make assumptions about the inequality of sums.